# con't convert cstring or string to int

Tags: c++

I wang to cin a int string, but failed, so I cin string then use strcpy to copy string to char, then use atoi to convert char to int. But still failed. Can you help me?
That's the error "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const_char*'.
Thanks very much.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <cstdlib>
    void juge_output(int input_one[]);
    void change(char middle_one[],int input_one[]);
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int input_one[1000],input_two[1000];
        char operat,middle_one[1000],middle_two[1000];
        string cin_one,cin_two;
        cin>>operat;
        cin>>cin_one;
        cin>>cin_two;
        strcpy(middle_one,cin_one.c_str());
        strcpy(middle_two,cin_two.c_str());
        change(middle_one,input_one);
        change(middle_two,input_two);
        juge_output(input_one);
        cout<<operat;
        juge_output(input_two);
        return 0;
    }
    void juge_output(int input_one[1000])
    {
        if(input_one[0]>0)
            cout<<input_one[0];
        if(input_one[0]<0)
            cout<<input_one[0];
        for(int i=1;i<1000;i+2)
        {
          if(input_one[i]>1)
          cout<<"X^"<<input_one[i];
          if(input_one[i]==1)
            cout<<"X";
        }
        for(int m=2;m<1000;m+2)
        {
            if(input_one[m]>0)
                cout<<"+"<<input_one[m];
            if(input_one[m]<0)
                cout<<input_one[m];
        }
    }
    void change(char middle_one[],int input_one[])
    {
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
            input_one[i]=atoi(middle_one[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Thanks, I am a fresh girl both in c++ and Stack Overflow. I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

std::cin will take an integer so you can directly do

```
int number;
std::cin >> number;
```

If you want to absolutely go with a string, the following should work too

```
std::string test_str;
int test_number;

std::cin >> test_str;

test_number = atoi(test_str.c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I can't use cin to input a int array. I want to cin something in an int array, but I shouldn't use for or while or do while, because I don't have a sign which can be used to stop cin.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use the string library function as such :

```
std::string str1 = "45";
std::string str2 = "3.14159";
std::string str3 = "31337 with words";
std::string str4 = "words and 2";

int myint1 = std::stoi(str1);
int myint2 = std::stoi(str2);
int myint3 = std::stoi(str3);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to change any value in a char array to a int array.